# How to get the looop equivalent command in teradata

Tags: sql, loops, case, teradata

I am very new to Teradata. Here I dont see any looping command to execute the following--
Input Structure

```
 A  B  C
 -- -- --
 1  b  c
 1  d  d
 1  c  d
 1 fx  b
```

Output_Structure--

```
A  B  C
-- -- --
1 fx  b
1  b  c
1  c  d
1  d  d
```

here if we implement with the CASE structure it will work, like

```
CASE
IF (B ='fx' THEN SELECT C AS A1)
CASE
IF(B!= 'fx' THEN SELECT C WHERE B=A1)
```

but if the number of records are more then we need to implement through LOOP. So any suggestion on this.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. You want the last row at the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a hierarchy, you need some recursive query for that.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (i, a,b,c) AS
(
  SELECT 1 AS i,a,b,c 
  FROM tab
  WHERE b = 'fx' -- start with the first value

  UNION ALL

  SELECT cte.i + 1, tab.* 
  FROM tab, cte
  WHERE cte.c = tab.b -- traverse the hierarchy
  AND cte.a = tab.a
  AND cte.b <> cte.c -- stop if b=c
)
SELECT * FROM cte
ORDER BY i
```

This might result in a loop if there'a a row like d-b, but **1 AS i** will error out if it exceeds 127, the max value of a byteint.

Protecting from infinite loop will be more complicated...

**Edit:**

To protect from infinite loop you need to create a path and check of the new value is already within the existing path:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (i, PATH, a,b,c) AS
(
  SELECT CAST(1 AS SMALLINT) AS i,
     '.' || CAST(TRIM(b) AS VARCHAR(10000)) || '.',
     a,b,c 
  FROM tab
  WHERE b = 'fx'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT cte.i + 1, 
     cte.PATH || TRIM(tab.b) || '.',
     tab.* 
  FROM tab, cte
  WHERE cte.c = tab.b
  AND cte.a = tab.a
  AND cte.PATH NOT LIKE '%.' || TRIM(tab.b) || '.%'
)
SELECT * FROM cte
ORDER BY 1;
```

The size of the path VarChar must be large enough to accommodate the largest possible recursion level.

Comment: Hi, can you please show me how the query will be in case the row is d-b just as you mentioned. As I am getting infinite loop when there is a row like d-b.

Comment: @dnoeth wonderful solution above , can you please tell us how this works or some where we can learn such concepts.

Comment: @etl_god: Simply check the result of the query to see how it works. The path is the common solution to prevent endless loops and it's also needed to order a hierarchy correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `order by`?

```
select t.*
from table t
order by c, b, a;
```

"looping" in databases is used with set-based operations, such as joins and group by.

Comment: Order by will not work here. See there is a chain relation. Column C data will be column B data in the next row. So in order to get this king og structure LOOP will be useful

Comment: @sgupdate1988 . . . You need to clarify the question.  This `order by` produces your desired output.

Comment: Ok, the requirement is for the first row column B has to be populated by 'fx'. For second row B column data will be populated by 1st row C column data. Similarly for third row B column data will be populated by 2nd row C column data. All these records are there in the input table, you need to arrange the records according to above rule.

Comment: @sgupdate1988 . . . Tables represent unordered sets.  There is no concept of "first row", unless you have another column such as an id that identifies a row as being first.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The identifier for the first row is column B has to be populated by 'fx'. So from input table last row will be selected as the first row of output table and then the the rule I mentioned in my previous comment will be followed to frame the rest of the rows in output table