# Teradata Recursive SQL to find Parents of Parent of given Child table

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have installed the Teradata Express and loaded publicly available database for teradata called 'Finance' in it.

It has some parent-child relationships using PK-FK.

My requirement is to find out all the parents,grant parents of the given child.

I have made use of `DBC.All_RI_Parents` metadata table and written a recursive SQL to find out the same but it is not giving the parents of parent and great parents of given child.

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE
(indexid,
indexname,
parentdb,
parenttable,
parentkeycolumn,
childdb,
childtable,childkeycolumn,
DEPTH) AS
(
select indexid,indexname,parentdb,parenttable,parentkeycolumn,
childdb,childtable,childkeycolumn,1 AS DEPTH 
from DBC.All_RI_Parents where childdb='finance' and childtable='fin_loan'
UNION ALL
SELECT par.indexid,par.indexname,par.parentdb,par.parenttable,par.parentkeycolumn,
par.childdb,par.childtable,par.childkeycolumn ,
CTE.DEPTH + 1
FROM CTE INNER JOIN DBC.All_RI_Parents par
ON CTE.parentkeycolumn = par.childkeycolumn
and CTE.parenttable = par.childtable
and CTE.parentdb = par.childdb
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

I have downloaded the dataset from

https://community.teradata.com/t5/Blog/Demo-databases-for-download/ba-p/85684

Please let me know if I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by looking deeply into data that I should not add `CTE.parentkeycolumn = par.childkeycolumn` as column name can be different. After removing this,It is working perfectly,

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE
(indexid,
indexname,
parentdb,
parenttable,
parentkeycolumn,
childdb,
childtable,childkeycolumn,
DEPTH) AS
(
select indexid,indexname,parentdb,parenttable,parentkeycolumn,
childdb,childtable,childkeycolumn,1 AS DEPTH 
from DBC.All_RI_Parents where childdb='finance' and childtable='fin_loan'
UNION ALL
SELECT par.indexid,par.indexname,par.parentdb,par.parenttable,par.parentkeycolumn,
par.childdb,par.childtable,par.childkeycolumn ,
CTE.DEPTH + 1
FROM CTE INNER JOIN DBC.All_RI_Parents par
ON 
CTE.parenttable = par.childtable
and CTE.parentdb = par.childdb
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Comment: You should switch to `All_RI_ParentsV` (never use a legacy non-V-view). If you're only interested in relations on table level you might use `RI_Distinct_ParentsV` instead. Caution: if there's a cross relation (e.g. A-B-A or A-B-C-A) you'll get an endless recursion (actually in your case a *numeric overflow* when you reach a DEPTH of 128). Btw, thanks for using my demo data :-)

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth , Anything that we can do to avoid endless recursion?

Comment: You need to aadd a *path* variable, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25895902/2527905